# Spacy: How to create a document from the sentence tokenized text?

Tags: python, spacy

I have text which is already sentence tokenized and wonder how to make a spacy document from it?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I came up with the following simple solution:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
sents = [['sentence', 'one'], ['sentence', 'two']]
doc = nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list([t for s in sents for t in s])
for t in doc:
    t.is_sent_start = False
i = 0
for s in sents:
    doc[i].is_sent_start = True
    i += len(s)
```

Comment: The `snts_orig` variable is never defined. It's also unclear what you're asking and, thus, what this is a solution to. First you just concatenate all the tokens into a single string and make that string a document, except you later mark some of those tokens as sentence-initial. What for, though?

Comment: @arturomp This solution enables me to skip spacy's default token and sentence tokenization steps. This way I can use custom tokenization method and still create a document object. And I don't "concatenate all the tokens into a single string", but feed a list of them so that the indices are preserved.

Comment: Your question doesn't give this context. May make sense to add some of this explanation to your initial post. (And yes, you're right, "string" should've been "list".)